# In JavaFx, How can I wrap the BorderPane by ScrollPane

Tags: java, javafx

I want to make scroll by wrapping my BorderPane. I tried like this, but it doesn't work. What's my problem?

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Drawing Test");

        VBox content = new VBox(5);
        ScrollPane scroller = new ScrollPane(content);
        scroller.setFitToWidth(true);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();     
        initRects(root);

        content.getChildren().add(root);

        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(scroller, null, null, null, null), 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    void initRects(BorderPane root){
         DrawRect(root, 0);
         DrawRect(root, 100);
         DrawRect(root, 200);
         DrawRect(root, 300);
    }

    void DrawRect(BorderPane root, double y){
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(50, 50 + y, 900, 50);
        rect.setFill(Color.DODGERBLUE);
        root.getChildren().add(rect);
    }
}
```

Here is the result view.

[image]

Comment: There are 2 BorderPanes you are creating, which borderpane are you trying to wrap?

Comment: @Oswald Presumably 'scroller': `new BorderPane(scroller, ...`

Comment: What are you expecting to see that you're not seeing? If you want a horizontal scroll bar, you should remove the `setFitToWidth(true)` line, and you should not use a `BorderPane` as the root (the rectangles are not "managed" in the border pane, so they don't affect the layout calculations): use a plain `Pane` instead.

Comment: Not that it will do anything useful, but you can add the line `scroller.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);` to see the scrollbar, so you know the scroll pane is there.

Comment: @user1803551 The scroll pane is there, it just doesn't think scroll bars are needed because the border pane isn't reporting its size as large enough to require them. This is because, I think, the rectangles aren't part of its layout computations (in a border pane, only nodes places in the five regions - top, right, bottom, left, center - are included in layout computations).

Comment: @James_D I know, but the OP doesn't seem to. I understood that the OP thinks there should be a scroll pane but there isn't, so I showed them a way to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `BorderPane` will perform its layout calculations (including the calculations for how large it wants/needs to be) by looking at the nodes placed in the five regions top, right, bottom, left, center.

Since the rectangles are simply added directly to the border pane's list of child nodes, and are not laid out directly by the border pane at all, the border pane does not report any required size. Consequently, the scroll pane wrapping it does not know that it needs to include scroll bars.

If you want to display these rectangles, a plain `Pane` is a better container for them (they basically manage their own layout, so you don't want a pane that manages layout of the child nodes):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Drawing Test");

        VBox content = new VBox(5);
        ScrollPane scroller = new ScrollPane(content);
        scroller.setFitToWidth(true);

        Pane root = new Pane();     
        initRects(root);

        content.getChildren().add(root);

        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(scroller, null, null, null, null), 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    void initRects(Pane root){
         DrawRect(root, 0);
         DrawRect(root, 100);
         DrawRect(root, 200);
         DrawRect(root, 300);
    }

    void DrawRect(Pane root, double y){
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(50, 50 + y, 900, 50);
        rect.setFill(Color.DODGERBLUE);
        root.getChildren().add(rect);
    }
}
```

This now produces the vertical scroll bar, which is (just) required for this content.

Note that the line

```
scroller.setFitToWidth(true);
```

forces the content to be the same width as the scroll pane's viewport, so it will effectively prevent any horizontal scroll bar from being displayed (and, in this case, clip the contained pane). If you remove that, you will also see the horizontal scroll bar (which is what I suspect you want):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Drawing Test");

        VBox content = new VBox(5);
        ScrollPane scroller = new ScrollPane(content);
//        scroller.setFitToWidth(true);

        Pane root = new Pane();     
        initRects(root);

        content.getChildren().add(root);

        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(scroller, null, null, null, null), 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    void initRects(Pane root){
         DrawRect(root, 0);
         DrawRect(root, 100);
         DrawRect(root, 200);
         DrawRect(root, 300);
    }

    void DrawRect(Pane root, double y){
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(50, 50 + y, 900, 50);
        rect.setFill(Color.DODGERBLUE);
        root.getChildren().add(rect);
    }
}
```

[image]